# What is `clojure.main` in the REPL command?

Tags: clojure, clojure-repl

On the [Clojure Getting Started page](http://clojure.org/getting_started), it shows to start the REPL like this:

```
java -cp clojure-1.5.1.jar clojure.main
```

The first argument is a file, which can also be specified via the environment variable `CLASSPATH`. But what is `clojure.main`?

Comment: Highly recommend you use [lein](http://leiningen.org/), so that you can (mostly) forget all about this java / classpath nonsense.

Comment: If you think you got your answer, would you please pick it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the main class of the JAR file:  [org.clojure/clojure/1.5.1/META-INF/maven/org.clojure/ clojure/pom.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org%24maven2@org.clojure%24clojure@1.5.1@META-INF%24maven%24org.clojure%24clojure%24pom.xml)

```
<archive>
    <manifest>
      <mainClass>clojure.main</mainClass>
    </manifest>
</archive>
```

For more info : [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used Java, so I hadn't encountered that.